# Java Stream converter Map<String, Obj> para List<Obj>

Tags: java, lista, stream, collection, map

Eu tenho esse objeto preenchido:

```
    Map<String, List<LogLine>> logMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

E depois de fazer um filtro, gostaria de uma lista plana dele, mas só consigo criar lista de lista

```
List<List<LogLine>>  foo = logMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(map -> map.getValue().size() > parameters.getThreshold())
            .map(map -> map.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Como consigo criar apenas um List com todos os LogLine utilizando stream? Tentei utilizar o flatMap, mas o compilador não deixa.

Comment: Então sei problema é transformar de `Map<K, List<V>>` para `List<V>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o operador que você quer é o `flatMap`:

```
List<LogLine> foo = logMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(map -> map.getValue().size() > parameters.getThreshold())
                .flatMap(map -> map.getValue().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Ele subistitui a stream atual [`logMap.entrySet().stream()`] por uma nova stream produzida ao aplicar uma função mapeadora a cada elemento [`map.getValue().stream()`].

Comment: Exatamente, eu fiz exatamente a mesma coisa um pouco depois.